# Gradle plugin 1.4.0-beta6 doesn't work with minification and repackageclasses option

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, proguard

Plugin version: com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.4.0-beta6
Build type config:

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
        shrinkResources true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-project.txt'
    }
}

minSdkVersion 9
targetSdkVersion 23
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion '23.0.1'
```

The build cannot be finished because of exception in gradle task. This is extremaly important, because class repackaging fixes many issues on Samsung devices with precompiled support library sources.

Error:
:myHeart:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForGooglePlayRelease FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task ':myHeart:transformClassesAndResourcesWithProguardForGooglePlayRelease'.

  > java.io.IOException: Can't write [H:\Projekty\my-heart\myHeart\build\intermediates\transforms\CLASSES_and_RESOURCES\FULL_PROJECT\proguard\GooglePlay\release] (Can't read [H:\Projekty\my-heart\myHeart\build\intermediates\classes\GooglePlay\release] (H:\Projekty\my-heart\myHeart\build\intermediates\transforms\CLASSES_and_RESOURCES\FULL_PROJECT\proguard\GooglePlay\release\happy\hacking\con.class (The system cannot find the file specified)))
- Try:
  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

proguard file:

```
-repackageclasses 'happy.hacking'

-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }

-keep class android.support.v7.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.app.** { *; }

-keep class android.support.v13.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v13.app.** { *; }


#To remove debug logs:
-assumenosideeffects class android.util.Log {
    public static *** d(...);
    public static *** v(...);
    public static *** w(...);
}

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable
```

I have filed an issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=190386&thanks=190386&ts=1445003690

Comment: okay .just down .use `1.4.0-beta4` .Gradle plugin `1.4.0-beta6` buggy

Comment: Let me inform .Actually we avoid beta version .Not stable

Comment: I have this problem again. I dunno if it's related, but it appeared, when I have migrated png icons to vector icons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.4 update to the Android Studio stable release channel**. Most of the work and enhancements for Android Studio 1.4 are under the hood.

**@Szymon Klimaszewski** Trying to use Stable version .

### What is Beta Version

> A version of a piece of software that is made available for testing.

For your requirement Use **`1.4.0-beta4 instead of 1.4.0-beta6`** .`1.4.0-beta6` is buggy .

Read this article

http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to IntelliJ Amiya it turned out that 1.4.0-beta6 is buggy, but 1.4.0-beta4 works totally fine.